# sqlalchemy check if object is in model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to be able to add an invitee to an event like so:

```
e = events.get(1)
u = users.get(1)
e.invitees.append(u)
```

and then in my service layer I'd like to be able to have a function like:

```
def add_invitee(self, event, user):
    if user in self.get(event).invitees:
        raise OroposError(u'User already invited')
    event.invitees.append(user)
    return self.save(event), user
```

A few things happen when I tried this. When I tried to use my function I get this error:

> InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably
>   unsupported type. u'SELECT events.id AS events_id, events.user_id AS
>   events_user_id, events.event_name AS events_event_name,
>   events.event_mesg AS events_event_mesg, events.start_date AS
>   events_start_date, events.end_date AS events_end_date,
>   events.event_status AS events_event_status, events.rsvp AS
>   events_rsvp, events.created AS events_created \nFROM events \nWHERE
>   events.id = ?' (,)

and when I try e.invitees.append(u) I get this error:

```
  File "/Users/f/.virtualenvs/Oropos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1057, in append
    item = __set(self, item, _sa_initiator)
  File "/Users/f/.virtualenvs/Oropos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1029, in __set
    item = getattr(executor, 'fire_append_event')(item, _sa_initiator)
  File "/Users/f/.virtualenvs/Oropos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 733, in fire_append_event
    item, initiator)
  File "/Users/f/.virtualenvs/Oropos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 910, in fire_append_event
    value = fn(state, value, initiator or self)
  File "/Users/f/.virtualenvs/Oropos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1140, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event
    child_impl = child_state.manager[key].impl
KeyError: 'event'
```

This has stumped me for a while.  Any suggestions?

Here are the models associated with my problem.

```
class EventJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer):
    pass


class Event(EventJsonSerializer, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'events'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    event_name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    event_mesg = db.Column(db.Text)
    start_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    end_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    event_status = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    rsvp = db.Column(db.Date)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=get_current_time)

    invitees = db.relationship('Invite', backref=db.backref('event'))
    proposals = db.relationship('Proposal', backref=db.backref('event'))


class InviteJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer):
    pass


class Invite(InviteJsonSerializer, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'invites'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = db.Column(db.Date, default=get_current_time)
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    event_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('events.id'))

    user = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys='Invite.user_id', lazy='joined')


class ProposalJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer):
    pass


class Proposal(ProposalJsonSerializer, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'proposals'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = db.Column(db.Date, default=get_current_time)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    event_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('events.id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you are trying to add a `User` instance to the list of `Invite` instances, are you sure that is right?

According to your code, `e.invitees` contains the `Invite` instances that have a foreign key `event_id` pointing to the `Event` instance `e`. If you want your `invitees` to represent a many-to-many relationship towards the `User` table (which is implied by the two foreign keys there), you probably need to make it into an [association table](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many). Also, I would dare to guess one `User` can have only one `Invite` to a single `Event`, which means that the fields should be associated with a [UniqueConstraint](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.UniqueConstraint) table argument.